# How to save as .PNG file as default in Photoshop CS3?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

by default it saves as .psd how do i change it to .png by default because its buggin to change each and every time !!

Answer (score 5):

The PNG format can not hold the minimum information that is contained in an image in Photoshop, even if it's a single layer RGB image. For example, the PNG format doesn't support color profiles, and an image in Photoshop always has a color profile.

So, saving as PNG is really exporting. When you load the image into Photoshop again, there is no guarantee that all settings are the same.

Comment: You are correct about exporting and that it doesn't have all the needed data, but PNG format does in fact allow storing an ICC colour profile information in the image (though it is better to get rid of it when saving for web, since different browsers - *cough* IE, - may treat it in a strange way). Still, it is best to save work in PSD, and then export it to PNG when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Saving a Photoshop document as PNG is a data-loss operation. There's a specific menu to save images for the web. Good old "Save" menu is normally use for the native format.

Comment: yes,but how do i save it as an image ? i have to use the save option and then select PNG each and everytime right ??

Comment: Use the "Save for Web & Devices" menu twice and see what happens ;-)

Comment: wrong: use the "save for web" item to save it as a png or jpg or gif or anything else. "Save" is to save the photoshop image with historic and layers and so on...

Answer (score 1):

It will always save as a PNG... as long as you haven't added anything that a PNG can't contain.

Basically it sounds like you're adding layers. As soon as you do, Photoshop will save your PNG file as a PSD to save your layers for you. To stop this FLATTEN the image and *then* press CTRL-S. It will save the image to whatever format you opened it in.