# How to select png format as default for save in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save as .PNG file as default in Photoshop CS3?](https://superuser.com/questions/203113/how-to-save-as-png-file-as-default-in-photoshop-cs3)

I very often save my files to png file, but when I save in **Save As dialog** I always see psd extension and I have to shoose other (e.g. png). Where I can set save to png file as default?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use this small script (and bound it to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>):

```
try {main(); } catch(e){} 
function main(){ 
    activeDocument.saveAs(app.activeDocument.path, SaveDocumentType.PNG, false, Extension.LOWERCASE); 
}
```

It will still prompt me for a file name, but the **Format** dropdown menu will be set to PNG by default. The first line just prevents any error messages from popping up if I click "**Cancel**" on the **Save As** window.

If you want it to save the PNGs in a specific folder, replace `app.activeDocument.path` with your preferred path.